# Adding some extra rewrite code to existing main rewrite code

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I currently have this in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*),(.*)$ $2.php?rewrite_params=$1&page_url=$2

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*(.*) [OR] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C).*script.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|[|%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|[|%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
```

I want to add some new code that rewrites:

```
stores/some-name/
```

to:

```
shop.php?shop_id=some-name
```

How can I do this without affecting the other rewrites or the other rewrites affecting the addition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your new rule in the end:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*),(.*)$ $2.php?rewrite_params=$1&page_url=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*(.*) [OR] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C).*script.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|[|%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|[|%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]

RewriteRule ^stores/([0-9a-z.-]+)/?$ shop.php?shop_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Awesome - I remember you helped me the other day as well. Thanks for all your help! The shop name will actually only contain alphanumeric characters as well as hyphens and periods; so I guess I could change it go `RewriteRule ^stores/([0-9A-Za-z\-.]+)/?$ shop.php?shop_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]` ?